# How to get icon from .NET executable (.exe) - Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon doesn't work

Tags: .net, icons

How to get icon from .NET executable (.exe)? - Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that's a .NET assembly it should work Fine.

at least for .NET Framework v :
**4.8 - 4.7.2 - 4.7.1 - 4.7 - 4.6.2 - 4.6.1 - 4.6 - 4.5.2 - 4.5.1 - 4.5 - 4.0 - 3.5 - 3.0 - 2.0** .

However you can always try to p/invoke winapi for that :

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ExtractAssociatedIcon(IntPtr hInst, StringBuilder lpIconPath, out ushort lpiIcon);
```

Also check [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIcon.html) for more infos .